# Making a F# type a measure as well?

Tags: types, f#, units-of-measurement

I'm reading Friendly F# and it has this code in the book

```
[<Measure>]
type Vector2<[<Measure>]'a> =
{
   X: float<'a>
   Y: float<'a>
}
```

So this code is meant to be used with F# and VS 2010. I'm currently using VS2012.

VS2012 is showing an error. Is this is F# version issue? If so, what is the right way?

Error it's showing is:

`Error  4   A type definition requires one or more members or other declarations. If you intend to define an empty class, struct or interface, then use 'type ... = class end', 'interface end' or 'struct end'.`

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: In 2012, the code is showing an error. I should have put that in the OP.

Comment: If you're running small examples out of a book, I suggest you try VSCode + Ionide. It has excellent support for F# scripts, which means you can execute your code by sending it directly to the REPL, bypassing any compilation step. http://ionide.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an indentation problem:

```
type Vector2<[<Measure>]'a> =
    {
       X: float<'a>
       Y: float<'a>
    }

[<Measure>] type kg

{ X = 13.<kg> ; Y = 10.<_> }

// val it : Vector2<kg> = { X = 13.0; Y = 10.0 }
```

Comment: You were exactly right. Nothing issue with my code was that the `Measure` attribute right above was causing an error as well.